# Error: 'The specified deps.json does not exist' running dotnet publish Release

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab

I searched through all the topics connected with this issue but found no solutions to my problem. I'm trying to run dotnet publish in Release mode for our QA environment using GitLab but I'm getting an error **'The specified deps.json [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\projectPath\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\projectName.deps.json] does not exist'**. Everything is working fine in Debug configuration.

Below are all my used settings (some naming of files may be changed).

Exception Log:

```
$ cd DataProjectPath
$ dotnet ef database update -v --no-build -s "..\WebApiProjectPath"
Using project 'C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\DataProjectPath\DataProj.csproj'.
Using startup project '..\WebApiProjectPath\WebApiProjectPath.csproj'.
Writing 'C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\DataProjectPath\obj\DataProj.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\jenksvnuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFCA1.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\DataProjectPath\DataProj.csproj
Writing '..\WebApiProjectPath\obj\WebApiProjectPath.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\jenksvnuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFF61.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo ..\WebApiProjectPath\WebApiProjectPath.csproj
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\WebApiProjectPath\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\WebApiProjectPath.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\jenksvnuser\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --fx-version 2.1 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\DotnetTools\dotnet-ef\2.1.4\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" database update --assembly 
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\WebApiProjectPath\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\DataProj.dll --startup-assembly C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\WebApiProjectPath\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\WebApiProjectPath.dll --project-dir 
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\DataProjectPath\ --language C# --working-dir C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\DataProjectPath --verbose --root-namespace DataProj
The specified deps.json [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\7d2c6d1d\0\WebApiProjectPath\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\WebApiProjectPath.deps.json] does not exist
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 2147516545`
```

Gitlab CI/CD Configuration:

```
stages:
  - unit_test
  - build_deploy

unit_test:
 stage: unit_test
 script:
  - 'cd ProjectName'
  - 'dotnet test ProjectName.Common.Tests'
  - 'dotnet test ProjectName.Data.Tests'
  - 'dotnet test ProjectName.Repository.Tests'
  - 'dotnet test ProjectName.Service.Tests'
  - 'dotnet test ProjectName.WebApi.Tests'

# THIS DEPLOY WORKS IF CHANGED FROM RELEASE TO DEBUG
deploy_qa:
  stage: build_deploy
  script:
  - 'cd ProjectName'
  - 'SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=QA' 
  - 'dotnet publish --configuration Release --output C:\QA\core-web-api-build'
  - 'if exist \\server\c$\Apps\QA\core-web-api\ del /q \\server\c$\Apps\QA\core-web-api\*' 
  - '(robocopy C:\QA\core-web-api-build\ \\server\c$\Apps\QA\core-web-api /E) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0'
  - 'cd ProjectName.Data'
  - 'dotnet ef database update -v --no-build "..\ProjectName.WebApi"'
  - 'cd C:\QA\core-web-api-build'
  - 'dotnet ProjectName.MasterData.dll QA'
  environment:
    name: server
    url: http://adress:91
  when: manual
  #only:
  #- QA
```

Regards.